# Table skipping section?

Tags: tables, texshop

I have one main section along with 5 subsections. One of the subsections has a table that cannot fit in half a page, and hence needs to be fitted in the next one. However, the table skips all the other subsections !! How can I fix this ?

Here is the pic :

note:(The table should be under subsection 1.4.2)

[image]

Code used :

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Resources}
\label{resource}
    \begin{tabular}{|l |l |p{10cm}| }
.
.
.
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You need to insert a `\clearpage` *after* the `table` definition.

Comment: @Werner is it possible to use `[h!]` to force the table to be set exactly "here"?

Comment: @Werner But even if I have another table that can fit in the same subsection and page, `\clearpage` will create a new page instead.

Comment: @MarioS.E. adding `[h!]` did not do anything :(

Comment: @NLed: You need to read the following two posts: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31) and 
[Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://goo.gl/290dD).

Comment: don't ever use `[h]` which is almost certain to take a table to the end of the document. by using `[h]` you have prevented latex placing the float in almost all the float areas `t` top of page `b` bottom of page and `p` float pages would all be considered had you not used the optional argument to prevent the float being placed there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the advice, I did remove `[h]` but they still skip sections.

Comment: @Werner Adding `[!htbp]` did not fix the problem though, the table still skips sections.

Comment: Impossible to say without an example but you can use the placeins package to stop floats floating too far but if they are trying to float too far it is usually because the parameters are set incorrectly.

Comment: Do you have text in the subsections? Your image looks like a table of contents??

Comment: Try  `[!tbp]` without h. If this do not work  try to load the `afterpage` package and put `\afterpage{\clearpage}` somewhere before the new page. This must allow to  flush the unprocessed floats.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Nope I don't have text in subsections yet.

Comment: @NLed well don't worry about float positioning then, get on with writing the text:-)

Comment: \clearpage worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Werner recommendations and these two questions:

[Table skipping section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108227/table-skipping-section?noredirect=1#comment236729_108227)

[How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

I think you can try using:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}{H}
\centering
\caption{Resources}
\label{resource}
    \begin{tabular}{|l |l |p{10cm}| }
        a & b & c\\
                    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @NLed `H` is never the right answer though (which I can say with some certainty as it was my idea and initially my implementation) `H` just disables the entire latex float mechanism so it isn't a float at all it is a mechanism of last resort (if that).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What's the alternative ? Nothing is working unless i add the `H`

Comment: @NLed you didn't answer the question of whether there was any text in the sections (`H` essentially makes text by making it not a float) If the sections are all empty LaTeX has nowhere to put the float (and so you shouldn't worry about it until the text is written)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry I'm used to MS WORD and hence expected the flow to be the same. Nope the other sections are empty just as displayed in the picture. So once I fill them in with text it should automatically fix this ?

Comment: @NLed: The flow in LaTeX is very different from that of MS Word, since LaTeX has an engine to compile input into output. While MS Word has a WYSIWYG approach.